# How can I make my R nls model more stable?

Tags: r

I am new to R, and I am trying to automate some nonlinear modeling of several thousand sets of x,y data.  These data are experimental results representing exponential decay.  I want to model my data to this formula:

```
y = (y0 - plateau)*exp(-k*x) + plateau
```

I have created functions for the model and the initial value estimation:

```
expDecayModel <- function(predictor, k, y0, plateau) {
    (y0 - plateau)*exp(-k*predictor) + plateau
}

expDecayModelInit <- function (mCall, LHS, data) 
{
    xyframe <- sortedXyData(mCall[["predictor"]], LHS, data)
    x <- xyframe$x
    y <- xyframe$y

    y0 <- max(y)
    plateau <- min(y)
    ymid <- (y0 + plateau)/2

    closesty <- y[1]
    closestyindex <- 1
    for (i in 2:length(y)) {   
        if (abs(y[i] - ymid) < abs(closesty - ymid)) {   
            closesty <- y[i]
            closestyindex <- i
        }
    }
    xatclosesty = x[closestyindex]
    k = 1 / xatclosesty
    value = c(k, y0, plateau)
    names(value) <- mCall[c("k", "y0", "plateau")]
    value
}
```

I created the self-starter like so:

```
SSexpDecay <- selfStart(expDecayModel, expDecayModelInit, c("k", "y0", "plateau"))
```

I then try to execute the model like this:

```
fitmodel <- nls(y ~ SSexpDecay(x, k, y0, plateau), data = AllData)
```

For some data sets, this seems to work nicely.  For others, it does not.  I'd like to know either what I'm doing wrong, or things that I can do to make my automated task more robust.  My initial value selection is (intentionally) intended to mimic those in [GraphPad Prism](http://graphpad.com/prism/Prism.htm), and at least for the data set below, the initial values for my three parameters are identical.

So, what can I do to improve this?

An example data set that fails is [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/wdVQW/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the built-in self-starting models are usually sufficient. I just got it to work for your data with `SSasymp`, so perhaps use that as a base if you need some option that it doesn't provide.

```
AllData = read.table('data.txt', header=T)

fit = nls(y ~ SSasymp(x, Asym, r0, lrc), data=AllData)

x.new = data.frame(x=with(AllData, seq(min(x), max(x), len=100)))
pred = predict(fit, x.new)

dev.new(width=5, height=5)
plot(AllData)
lines(x.new$x, pred, col='red')
```

[image]